# boot loop after flashing partitions from stock firmware

Tags: boot-loop, fastboot, sony-xperia-p

I have Arch linux installed and have installed android-tools(so fastboot and adb commands are available).

Because I had a problem with kingroot I needed to flash the phone to stock.

I had stock firmware downloaded and extracted it to see the sin files inside it.

I flashed partitions using these commands :

```
fastboot flash system system.sin
fastboot flash userdata userdata.sin
fastboot flash cache cache.sin
fastboot reboot
```

Now the first two succeeded but the third one failed saying partition not found(guess I don't have cache partition for some reason).

After that I got stuck in a boot loop.

Normally sony Xperia P boots with Sony word and then to Xperia word(which blinks) and then to android but it's stuck in the Sony word.

I tried powering off the phone and flashing the boot partition using this command :

```
fastboot flash boot kernel.sin
```

rebooted, the same problem.

I tried to flash FOTAKernel but I don't seem to have this partition.

I tried also `fastboot reboot-bootloader` and then reboot but the same.

I've read the boot-loop wiki, both Safe mode and recovery mode are unreachable.

I would try to flash the other .sin files But I don't know to what partition they belong and google didn't help me to get this information :3 .

So what to do ?

### Update

I forgot to mention that I tried to flash .ftf file using FlashTool 0.9.19.10, this tool didn't work, I click the lightning bolt, I chose the Flash mode, I choose the .ftf file(after putting it in ~/.flashtool/firmwares), after clicking ok it tells me to plug my device in fastboot mode.

I click Volumne Up while plugging the device and I see the blue(somewhat purple) Led light on.

I wait and wait and even when Flashtool said "Device connected in fastboot mode" it doesn't do anything but telling me to plug my device :3 .

### Device

Sony xperia P runing android 4.0.4, bootloader is unlocked but the phone is not rooted nor has custom recovery(so no CWM or TWRP here).

Comment: Have you tried flashing the `.ftf` file using Flashtool?  You can select the partitions that you wish to flash in that tool. Also, if you're on Unlocked bootloader, you can flash custom recovery with `fastboot flash recovery recovery.img` command

Comment: @Manubhargav yes I tried Flashtool, about custom recovery my phone isn't officially supported by neither TWRP nor CWM, I found an article on xda developers about TWRP for my phone, unfortunetly it needs a working root phone.  

If you know of a custom recovery that I can flash even with the situation my device in , I'd appriciate it .

Comment: @Manubhargav anyway what will custom recovery do if I can't even boot into recovery mode :3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer.

FlashTool worked after using Flashmode, it wasn't working because of my mistake, I was plugging the device in fastboot mode instead of flashmode.

After I flashed it it works great.